# Checking if a string is a prefix of a possible regex match

Tags: python, regex, tree, wildcard, directory-structure

I want to traverse a tree structure, but only those parts that match a wildcard expression, a la python glob, where double asterisk means 'any number of subdirs'.

For example, say my wildcard expression is /*/foo/**/bar/. This would match /a/foo/bar/, /b/foo/note/bar/, but not /a/bar/foo/bar/. You get the idea.

My problem is that when traversing the tree structure, I need to know whether the current dir *could possibly* match the wildcard expression as a prefix. So I do want to traverse the directory /a/, but not /a/bar/, because I know the latter will never match the wildcard expression.

The wildcard expression I will rewrite to a regular expression, of course.

Comment: Careful with how you define prefix. Would you accept `/a/fo` as a valid match? This is not just me being pedantic, since I think considering in detail the question of how you define a prefix should get you on your way to an algorithm. Also this does not strike me as a "regex, of course!" kind of problem, since it will probably take a lot of thought and care to construct a regex properly. Not that regex is necessarily not useful here, but considering how to apply it most elegantly and not trying to catch all with a single regex might open up more doors to beautiful places.

Comment: The easiest case for me is when your traversal reaches `**` in which case all subtrees are valid prefixes.

Comment: Anyway I'd come up with some kind of logical grouping for your regex sub-patterns, put those groups in a list, and pass a sublist down minus the head (and also not, in the ** case) to the next level of your tree when the head matches.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code for starters. I assume you have each "directory" in the path and pattern as elements in a pair of lists:

```
def traverse(pattern_list, path_list):
    if pattern_list[0] == '**':
        traverse_children(pattern_list, path_list[1:])
    if current_matches(pattern_list[0], path_list[0]):
        traverse_children(pattern_list[1:], path_list[1:])
        # Other things you might want to do in the case of a valid prefix

def current_matches(pattern_atom, path_atom):
    return pattern_atom in (path_atom, '*', '**')
```